# Almost sure convergence for an uncountable sequence of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Suppose we have a process ($X(t) : t\geq0$).

What does it mean for say $\lim_{t \to 0}X(t) = 0$ almost surely.

The reason I am confused is because I have only ever almost sure convergence for a countable sequence of random variables.

Would it be true that if every countable sequence $(t_n) \to 0$ we have $\lim_{n \to \infty}X(t_n) = 0$ almost surely, then $\lim_{t \to 0}X(t) = 0$ almost surely holds?

Comment: It means there is an event $A$ of probability $0$ such that $X_t(\omega) \to 0$ for every $\omega \in \Omega \setminus A$. For your second question the answer is NO.

Comment: This is just an addition to the comment of @Kavi Rama Murthy: to guarantee that there *is* such an event, defined by a countable (dense) set of $t$, there are usually assumptions concerning the regularity of the trajectories of a process $X(t)$, e.g. right continuity.